# Honeywell Xenon 1900 barcode reader | read data | virtual com port

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I have the following barcode reader:
https://www.honeywellaidc.com/products/barcode-scanners/general-duty/xenon-1900g-1902g

Installed the drivers like described below:
http://hsm.force.com/publickb/articles/HSM_Article/How-to-get-the-scanner-to-communicate-via-virtual-COM-port-USB-serial-driver

And configurated the scanner to virtualize a com port. The scanner is plugged in and my device manager has detected it:

[image: deviceManager]

[image: details]

Here is my c# code:

```
class Program
{
    private static SerialPort _ReaderPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _ReaderPort.DataReceived += ReaderPortOnDataReceived;
        _ReaderPort.ErrorReceived += ReaderPortOnErrorReceived;
        _ReaderPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _ReaderPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        _ReaderPort.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        _ReaderPort.Open();            
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ReaderPortOnErrorReceived(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs serialErrorReceivedEventArgs)
    {
    }

    private static void ReaderPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    {
    }
}
```

I don't even receive an event! I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working. Here is the **magical code**

```
        _ReaderPort.DtrEnable = true;
        _ReaderPort.RtsEnable = true;
```